# Deleting image displayed in Windows Phone Image Control

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have the following code to display image in an Image control.

```
var stream = isolatedStorage.OpenFile(imageName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
imageControl.Source = bitmapImage;
```

I also want to give the user option to delete the image. I have the following code for it.

```
myImage.Source = null;
isolatedStorage.DeleteFile(imageName);
```

But this results in IsolatedStorageException with the message 'Unable to delete the file'.

I can't use stream source property of the bitmap or use Cache option, since Windows phone doesn't support them.

Any other workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need to close the `fileStream` before deleting the file.

Try

```
stream.Close()
```

or something like this before deleting the file

**OR**

If your `isolatedStorage` variable is of type `IsolatedStorageFile` then you can directly use

```
isolatedStorage.DeleteFile("yourfilename.ext");
```

Comment: Your first solution works. 2nd solution doesn't work. It is of type IsolatedStorageFile only obtained with IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().